# Non-trivial Polynomial Solution to $P(x)=(P'(x))^2, P(2)=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, polynomials

> Find a nonzero polynomial $P(x)$ passing through the point $(2,0)$ and satisfying the equation $P(x)=P'(x)^2$.

Well, so far I got that $P(2) = 0$ and so $P(2) = P'(2)^2 = 0$, which means that $P'(2) = 0$ as well. If a derivative is 0, that means the actual function must be a constant that passes (2,0)... But I can't seem to think of anything else other than 0 polynomial, which the problem already ruled out. Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: `If a derivative is 0, that means the actual function must be a constant` No, that's only if the derivative is *identically* $0\,$.

Comment: must be degree exactly two. Let $P(x) = a x^2 + bx + c$ and find $a,b,c$

Comment: @dxiv I'm sorry, but could you explain what you mean by "identically 0"?

Comment: What does it mean when the derivative of a function is zero at a point?

Comment: @Helena `what you mean by "identically 0"` Meaning that the derivative is *the* zero polynomial. Just because the derivative happens to be $0$ at some point, doesn't mean that it is $0$ everywhere. Consider the non-zero polynomial $P(x)=x^2-2x$ for example, whose derivative is zero at $P'(1)=0$..

Comment: Helena, if $P(x) = a x^2 + b x + c,$ what is $P'(x) \; ?$ And then what is $(P'(x) )^2 \; ?$

Comment: @ dxiv and Will Jagy, okay now I got it. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited the question to make the title more descriptive and added the differential equations tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the desired polynomial must satisfy $P(x)=(P'(x))^2$. Hence,
$$\deg(P(x))=\deg((P'(x))^2)=2\deg(P'(x))=2(\deg(P(x))-1)$$
since $\deg(P'(x))=\deg(P(x))-1$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Suppose $P$ is a solution of degree $n$. What is the degree of $(P')^2$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by now you have calculated the answer, so for anyone interested, the solution is:
$$P(x) = \frac{x^2}{4} - x + 1$$

$P'(x)=\frac{x}{2}-1$

${P'(x)}^2 = \frac{x^2}{4} - x + 1$

$P(2) = \frac{2^2}{4}-2+1 = 0$